# Including enums defined in header

Tags: c, struct, enums, header

I have been fiddling with enums for a while and wanted to try to use them in a project. The project structure is as follows:

// protocol.h

```
#ifndef PROTOCOL_H
#define PROTOCOL_H
enum C_C    {P_NORTH            =   0,
            P_WEST              =   1,
            P_SOUTH             =   2,
            P_EAST              =   3};

#endif
```

// other.h

```
#include "protocol.h"
struct cmd {
    enum C_C code : 4;
};

void make_cmd(struct cmd*, enum C_C);
```

This file triggers the following errors:

```
field 'code' has incomplete type
'enum C_C' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
```

// other.c

```
#include "other.h"

void make_cmd(struct cmd* cmd, enum C_C code) {
    cmd->code = code;
}
```

This throws the following errors:

```
conflicting types for 'make_cmd'
```

I have tried changing the enum to a type using typedef with no luck. This happens also with function definitions which rely on this type of parameters.

Will throw the following error:

type of formal parameter 2 is incomplete

Thanks for your help.

This only happens when using the defined enum in another header, either for structs or for functions prototypes.

I do believe there must be some issue with the compilation order. I have tested in Xilinx SDK and Vitis with the same result.

protocol.h holds all the definitions of the enums and the structures to be used throughout the project. I was hoping by just including this one in the other headers the definitions would be available to build the other.h and other.c on top of that one.

Update:

I have moved the definition of the structure inside the protocol.h and it lets me add a member using the enum without issues. I guess the problem is when importing protocol.h into another header and trying to use the enum there the compiler has all of the headers in the

Comment: Please show where protocol.h and other.h are included.

Comment: `make_cmd` [**compiles**](https://www.godbolt.org/z/qvK5GrnTK) if `other.h` is included. There is something you're not telling us.

Comment: Don't _describe_ or paraphrase the compiler diagnostic, copy and paste them into the question verbatim.  They include more information that you have posted here.

Comment: There is nothing magic about the header files, the content is inserted exactly where you include it as if you had typed it directly.  You get the error message you describe in GCC  if `enum C_C` is not defined at the point it is referenced, so clearly the protocol.h file does not define the enum.  Possibly you have conditional compilation around it that is hiding it.  Certainly it should have include guards, not shown - if you copy and pasted those from another header without changing the guard macro name for example, including one header would hide the content of the other - just guessing.

Comment: Do you have include guards?  Have you used a unique guard name in each header?

Comment: You definitely did something wrong, but we don't have enough information to tell you what exactly is wrong

Comment: It was practically impossible to give the complete scope, sorry for this stupid question. The problem, as pointed out by @Clifford had to do with the guards. There was already another "protocol.h" somewhere in the BSP. Changed the name of the header and everything is working now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code compiles:

```
#include "other.h"

void make_cmd(struct cmd* cmd, enum C_C code) {
    cmd->code = code;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct cmd cmd;

    make_cmd(&cmd, P_WEST);
}
```

If you `#include "protocol.h"` as well you'll get an error (type redefinition) because it is already included in other.h.

Comment: That is true, but not an answer to the the question. It does not exhibit the same error message. My guess is he has include guards in two headers with the same guard macro name.

Comment: Thanks, yes infact the problem was with another header having the same name. Thus, my "protocol.h" was  skipped by the guards.

Comment: In fact is a hint, as it was a hint, as mentioned in my comment to @Clifford. The thing was the redefinition was protected by guards which didn't allow the compilation of "protocol.h". The actual solution was changing the name to the header given that "protocol.h" was already defined in the platform.

Comment: You have edited your question after I answered. Initially there was no guard. That's not fair to now say it was a hint.